# Openness of complement of countable sets

Tags: real-analysis

Take A = {p} ∪ {p_n | n∈N}
, {pn} converges to p

A' = {p}' ∩ {p_n | n∈N}'

Then how do we decide that A' is open?

I thought that since {p_n | n∈N}' ⊂ {p}' , A'= {p_n | n∈N}' = (-∞,p1)∪(p1, p2)∪(p2,p3)∪...∪(p_(n-1),p_n)∪...

union of open intervals is open..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is no.

Let $ A = \{ 1/n : n=1,2,3,\cdots \} $.  Then $ 0 \in A' $ but every open interval around $ 0 $ contains infinitely many points in $ A $ and therefore is not wholly contained in $ A' $.

---

If you now add the condition $p_n \to p$ then indeed $A'$ is open.  Using an infinite union of intervals to prove this will be difficult because you cannot be sure of the ordering of $\{ p, p_n \}$.  Instead consider either of the following.

---

(1) Because $p_n \to p$ and the limit of a convergent sequence is unique, the set $A$ can only have one limit point.  Therefore $A$ contains all its limit points and is closed.  The complement of a closed set is open, so $A'$ must be open.

---

(2) You can also argue directly.

Let $q \in A'$. Then $ q \neq p$ and $|p-q| > 0$.  Define $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}|p-q| $.  Then because $p_n \to p$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n > N$ we have $|p_n - p| < \varepsilon$.  That implies $|p_n - q| > \varepsilon$.  Now define $$\delta = \frac{1}{2}\min\{\varepsilon,  |p_1-q|, |p_2-q|, \cdots, |p_N-q| \}.$$  All points of $A$ lie outside the open interval of length $\delta$ centred on $q$, so the whole interval lies in $A'$.

We have shown for every $q \in A'$, $q$ lies inside an open interval wholly within $A'$.  Therefore $A'$ is open.

Comment: thanks.. Then how can I prove it open?

Comment: sorry for editing it late.. That was a big help. I really appreciate it!